# Add toggle property in v-b-popover for touch

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4, vuejs2, bootstrap-vue

I am using v-b-popover.
My devices are touch and mouse events.
So I am using v-b-popover.hover as a tag.
So I wanted to know, Is their anyway I can toggle the popover(show and hide) in both touch and mouse events.

```
<b-col v-for="lesson in Lessons">
<b-button
 v-b-popover.hover.bottom="lesson.lessonName">
{{lesson.lessonName}}
</b-button>
</b-col>
```

Comment: Please post code of what you have tried.

Comment: Added the code, Now you can use the reference

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `v-b-popover.hover.focus.bottom` directive for your buttons and then all your button can be triggered by `click` or `hover`, and it meets your requirements in mobile devices and mouse events,

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  mounted() {
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].addEventListener('click', e => {
      this.$root.$emit('bv::hide::popover')
    });
  }
})
```

```css
#app {
  margin: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.21.2/dist/bootstrap-vue.css" />

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.12/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.21.2/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <b-button v-b-popover.hover.focus.bottom="'Hellow World!'" variant="info">Your Button</b-button>
</div>
```

Comment: yeah i know this, But popover is opening but not closing in touch devices when i click once again on that button

Comment: i wanted it to be toggling when we click(tap on touch screen)

Comment: Updated the answer. I added `eventListener`. When you click on the screen, the `popover` will close.

Comment: For the first time it will work, but after that not working

Comment: I tried putting id dynamically as I am having lot of popover in a page(as used v-for in question).
```
 this.$root.$emit("bv::show::popover",id)
and
this.$root.$emit("bv::hide::popover",id)

Comment: The above listener works on all popovers. What do you mean that it's not working?

Comment: Not working means one tap on touch screen on popover , it opens.
then closes if you tap agian....

But if you tap again, popover didn't open

Comment: Maybe using `click` instead of `focus` solve your problem.

Comment: Already tried, but  no success.
I am thinking of @click="function_name(id)" 
And in that function i will add class hide and show as ifelse condition then it could work.

Answer (score 0):

The tooltip's `hover` trigger, includes *touch* on mobile by default. So it should already work with no changes if all you need is *touch* events on mobile, and hover on desktop.

```html
<b-button v-b-popover.hover="'Hello World!'">
  A tooltip is shown on hover on desktop, and touch on mobile.
</b-button>
```

If you want to support *mouse clicks* on desktop, you'll need an additional trigger. Either `click` or `focus` should work for that.

```html
<b-button v-b-popover.hover.click="'Hello World!'">
  A tooltip is shown on hover/click on desktop, and click on mobile.
</b-button>
```

Comment: yeah i know this, But popover is opening but not closing in touch devices when i click once again on that button

Comment: i wanted it to be toggling when we click(tap on touch screen)

Comment: If you're using  touch and `hover`, you close it by clicking outside (not on) the element. If you want to specifically toggle it on touch by pressing the element, then you need to use the `click hover` triggers. (order matters). However that also enables `click` for desktop users.

Comment: Tried by v-b-popover.click.hover . not working .
Toggling for touch devices not working

Comment: Not sure why it's not working for you. Worked for me when i tested it on my android device. You might have to look for another solution in that case.